# How List.size() works ? When list is an interface?

Tags: java, list, selenium

As `List` is an interface can somebody explain how `list.size()` works internally?

Where is the implementation given?

Comment: Any class that implements List, should implement the size method. Which is what is getting called when you do List.size

Comment: @Srinivas when i write , 
  List li=driver.findElements(By.xpath("")); and then use size , does that means driver.findElements must be using some implementation of List interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List`, as many other interfaces, has a bunch of implementations.

These implementations (have a look at the `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` classes) describe how the `List#size` should work while the interface just states that such a method should be present (and, therefore, implemented) in subclasses.

For example, both the `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` have a private field `size` which is returned from the `List#size`:

```
@Override
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

> Does that means `driver.findElements` must be using some implementation of `List` interface?

Yes, it uses a certain `List` implementation that defines how the size should be calculated.

Comment: Please let me know in case you get to know that specific implementation , thank you for the help.

Comment: @SoumyanshGupta, I don't use Selenium, but you can download the sources and find out by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you implement an interface, you're essentially getting a blueprint as to how your class should be built. You implement all the functions from the interface (unless you're making this class abstract). So the ArrayList or whatever data structure you're actually creating will have its own size() function already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

A list is not  an interface , i think you are asking about this question because Java platform says "interface list". That does not mean when you say `List list = new List();`it calls an interface. Interface is definition/specifications of all methods that a class provide. Here in above example `list` word refers to an object and you can only create an object if you have a class.

You can think of that your list class is in other package with functions which are listed as interface and you can use those function and developer of list class wants to tell you which function you can use and how you can use them but he does want you to change them.